# doctrine clear and embedded entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I don't understand why i have to clear embedded entities, can you explain me ?

I am in a big treatment so i pasted only the logic of the algorithm. I know i don't have to flush each time (i read batch processing in symfony doc)

With this code :

```
foreach ($buildings as $building) {
    $appartments = $this->em->getRepository('Appartment')->findByBuilding($building['id']);

    /**
     * @var $appartment Appartment
     */
    foreach ($appartments as $appartment) {


        $log = new Log();
        $log->setAppartment($appartment)
            ->setLabel('test');

        $this->em->persist($log);
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->clear(Log::class);

    }
    $this->em->clear(Appartment::class);
}
```

I have this error :

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Owner#appartment' that was not configured to cascade persist
```

But when i do :

```
$this->em->clear(Appartment::class);
$this->em->clear(Owner::class);
```

it works

This is an example, but in my project, i have a lot of related entities. Do i have to check all the relations to clear them ?

Can you explain me this problem ?

thanks

EDIT: here the entities (this post is an example so it is possible i make mistakes)

Appartment :

```
AppBundle\Entity\Appartment:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\AppartmentRepository
    table: appartment
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        ....
    oneToOne:
        owner:
            targetEntity: AppartmentOwner
            mappedBy: appart
```

Owner :

```
AppBundle\Entity\AppartmentOwner:
    type: entity
    table: appart_owner
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        ....
    oneToOne:
        appart:
            targetEntity: Appartment
            joinColumn:
                name: appart_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
```

Comment: by it works you mean you did have both entities saved AND linked to each other ?

Comment: By "it works", i mean that there is no error and my Log entity is created with the relation on the Appartment

Comment: why you have two flush ?

Comment: Copy / paste error. I edited my post.

Comment: can you show the entities ?

Comment: There is no need to use clear function here. Remove it and you'll have no problem. You'd save some memory using it, but you lose more using flush on every iteration on your foreach cycle. I'd consider flushing all building apartments or say every 20 iterations or so.

Comment: I am in a very big treatment. So i paste only the logic but i need to clear. If not, it takes too much memory. So i need to understantd what to do in this case

Comment: I Edited the post to give tou an example of my entites with the minimum because this is just an example i made to explain the problem. I have a lot of relations in my project. Thanks for your help